# Gracefully logout all connected ssh users on reboot

Tags: linux, ssh, systemd, shutdown

When I reboot my Linux server (BusyBox Linux) all ongoing ssh client connections run into a stucked state until a timeout on client side occurs. There is no message sent to the ssh client to produce a "Disconnect"  error message. This basically makes the ssh client appear like something is frozen.

I'am using systemd with this service config for sshd in version OpenSSH_5.8p2

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH Per-Connection Server
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -i
SuccessExitStatus=0 255
StandardInput=socket
```

Is there a way to configure a gracefull shutdown for the sshd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sshd sessions on my (rhel) server may be identified by:

```
~# ps -ef |grep sshd:
root     12120     1  0 10:18 ?        00:00:00 sshd: sysope [priv]
sysope   12132 12120  0 10:18 ?        00:00:00 sshd: sysope@pts/2
```

killing those processes will immediately close the connections. So adapt your sshd service file for systemd like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH Per-Connection Server
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -i
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/killall -9 sshd
SuccessExitStatus=0 255
StandardInput=socket
```

Comment: this answer helped me to find the solution i added  ExecStop=/usr/sbin/killall -9 sshd to my ssh service config above. Then the ssh client get an Disconnect